# No decrease in loss after lots traning

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I was trying to train a convolution network. But it is not improving, i.e. loss is not decreasing. And the train function is also terminating much more quickly than usual. Below is the minimal code to show the problem.

```
using Flux

data=rand(200, 100, 1, 50)

label=rand([0.0,1.0], 1, 50)

model=Chain(

   Conv((3,3), 1=>5, pad=(1,1)),
   MaxPool((2,2)),
   Conv((3,3), 5=>5, pad=(1,1)),
   MaxPool((2,2)),
   Conv((3,3), 5=>5, pad=(1,1)),
   MaxPool((2,2)),
   x->reshape(x, :, size(x, 4)),
   x->σ.(x),
   Dense(1500,100),
   Dense(100,1)
)

model(data)

loss=Flux.mse

opt=Descent(0.1)

param=params(model)

loss(model(data), label)  #=>0.3492440767136241

Flux.train!(loss, param, zip(data, label), opt)

loss(model(data), label)  #=>0.3492440767136241
```

Comment: Hey! I am not a user of Flux, but in case it is the example you are running, than I would expect exactly what you are describing: no result. You are modelling noise. Machine learning is learning complex patterns, not getting a magic eight ball.

Comment: But either way, this doesn't look like a programming question. I think it should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `Flux.train!` needs to be function which accepts the data, runs the model, and returns the loss. Its loop looks something like this:

```
for dtup in zip(data, label)
    gradient(() -> loss(dtup...), params)
    ...
end
```

But the function `loss` you provide doesn't call the model at all, it just compares the data point to the label directly.

There is more to fix here though. What's being iterated over is tuples of numbers, starting with `zip(data, label) |> first`, which I don't think is what you want. Maybe you wanted `Flux.DataLoader` to iterate batches of images?